# Implicit conversion of enumType(aka 'enum enumType') to 'id _Nullable' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c

enumType is my enum type's name, and enumValue is a variable of XXX type.
After I define enumType and enumValue, when I use `[dict setObject:enumValue forKey:@"key"];`, xcode hint title's message.

Finally solved:
use `@(enumValue)` replace `enumValue`.

Comment: Dictionary values need to be `NSObject`, while the enum is a primitive (Integer, or other "similar you used). So one solution is to wrap it into a `NSNumber`, as you did with `@(enumValue)`.